# Stop javascript div rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a script that makes a div rotating..
Now I'm trying to make only one rotation and stop the script.. can you help me?
How can I stop this script to only one rotation?
I'm new to this programming language.. D:

```
<body style="-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);">
    <div id="wrap">
        <p>some content</p>
        <script type="text/JavaScript">
            function getTransformProperty(element) {
                var properties = ['transform', 'msTransform', 'WebkitTransform', 'MozTransform' , 'OTransform'];
                var p;
                while (p = properties.shift()) {
                    if (typeof element.style[p] != 'undefined') {
                        return p;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
            var div = document.getElementById('wrap');
            var property = getTransformProperty(div);
            if (property) {
                var d = 0;
                setInterval(function () {div.style[property] = 'rotate(' + (d++ % 360) + 'deg)';}, 10);
            }
        </script>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is a pretty strange way of going about rotating a div. Have you considered using a class transition or CSS animation instead?

Comment: @JonathanBrooks you are right, maybe this is not the best way to do animations, but to fix the issue and with respect to the knowledge level, it's enough that he understands how to deal with intervals. And that you can clear them, stop them

Comment: @JonathanBrooks actually don't wanted to start a deep discussion, but I want to share this link with you, because you are speaking about good practices and so on.. so please it's worth reading https://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do it by clearing the `interval`.

```
if (property) {
    var d = 0;
    interval = setInterval(function () {
       d++;
       div.style[property] = 'rotate(' + (d % 360) + 'deg)';
       if (d == 360) clearInterval(interval); // clearInterval if 360deg reached.. 
    }, 10);
}
```

Comment: oh, yes you are right, this is because d++ returns first the last value and then increments.. I'll edit the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach isn't ideal. Your best bet would be to use a CSS class transition, like so:

```js
//setTimeout is merely for delaying the effect for display purposes
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("wrap").classList.add("rotate");
}, 1000);
```

```css
#wrap {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
            transition: transform 1s;
}

#wrap.rotate {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
<p>some content</p>
</div>
```

Much less code!

Comment: Can you explain why this should be the right answer?

Comment: I really don't understand why people thinks, that using css transitions is really good. I would say it's enough to build a slider, but it's definitely not ideal when it comes to performance. It may sound ridiculous because everybody know that css is powered by the gpu, but they forget, that gpu is calculating the props and slow rendering process is however done by the layout engine.. This is the reason why HTML5 game don't use css animations.. because they sucks actually..

Comment: This is a wrong conclusion. You are not modifying css with js you are modifying html element properties. CSS and Style of an element are different things.. And in my opinion the code is better readable when it's in one place.. And not in three.. Like give it a class with js and the search the 25 css files.. for this class... But I agree that good code is readable and maintainable.. Who will maintain your 25 css files?? You will, your whole life ;)

Comment: Hey please, I've seen complext js animations.. for example in green stock.. did you ever seen complex css animations.. ok fade in/out. But some years ago I did a fully responsive css animated cartoon figure, and it was complex. I ended with 300-400loc of SASS (for easier mod.) plus JS for the class handling.. And it took me about 200Lines to rewrite it in pure JS with more features and better readable code.. As I said I don't want mess with you, or discuss. I just did my experience with css animations.. But if you like it.. do it